# Draw an arrow pointing to a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, forest

Is it possible to draw an arrow pointing to a square bracket in a tree?
Still, how to write above and below the arrow?
This is the code I have. It follow the image of the target I have in mind.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={forked edge, anchor=center,
    }
    [,phantom,s sep=1cm
    [a b, for tree={grow'=east}
        [x]
        [y]
    ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need to use the `forest` package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
        for tree={forked edge, fork sep=0pt, anchor=center
    }
    [{}, for tree={grow'=east}
        [x]
        [y]
    ]
    \draw[<-] (.parent anchor) -- ++(-.5,0) node[midway, above] {a} node[midway, below] {b};
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can also do:

```
\begin{forest}
        for tree={forked edge, fork sep=0pt, anchor=center, child anchor=west
    }
    [{}, for tree={grow'=east}
        [x 
            []
            []
        ]
        [y]
    ]
    \draw[<-] (.parent anchor) -- ++(-.5,0) node[midway, above] {a} node[midway, below] {b};
    \draw[<-] (!1.child anchor) -- ++(-.5,0) node[midway, above] {a} node[midway, below] {b};
\end{forest}
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

Using `\forestset`, it is also possible to create a custom edge which you could use like follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\forestset{
    arrow/.style 2 args={
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},->]
            (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(\forestoption{fork sep},0)
            \forestoption{edge label} node[midway,above]{#1} node[midway,below]{#2};
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            ([xshift=\forestoption{fork sep}]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)
            \forestoption{edge label};
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
        for tree={forked edge, fork sep=.5cm, anchor=center, child anchor=west
    }
    [{}, for tree={grow'=east}
        [x, arrow={a}{b}
            [z, arrow={c}{d}]
            []
        ]
        [y]
    ]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
        for tree={forked edge, l=2cm, fork sep=1.5cm, anchor=center, child anchor=west
    }
    [{}, for tree={grow'=east}
        [x, arrow={longer}{words}
            [z, arrow={other}{stuff}]
            []
        ]
        [y]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the distances using the `fork sep` and `l` options:

[image]

Comment: I read your answer before editing. This one is way more clean. I use forest package because it's good when I want to build trees with lots of nodes. I still have a question: what to do if I want to add an arrow to another tree that has "x" (or "y", it doesn't matter) as a parent? I tried naming the node (like "name=f2"), but the result is not the one with the arrow touching square bracket.

Comment: +1 for imaginative second solution!

Comment: @Jasper Habicht, the last code, using \forestset, is perfect. It is exactly what I had in mind. Thanks a bunch. However, some problems appear when we write words (like, for example, "animal", "birds", "mammal" etc.) instead of letters ("a", "b", "x", "y", etc.).

Comment: That’s why I added a hint about how to scale this.

Comment: What about words instead of the letters "x", "y" and "z"?

Comment: You would probably need to increase the value for the `l` option. I did not change anything about the normal alignment behavior of the package. I suggest that you consult the manual if you are unsure about how to adjust spacing in a forest.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Jasper Habicht! Everything's ok.